# How to write a loop while in Robot Framework

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I make my first simple test case, and I have one problem.

Is it possible write a loop in Robot Framework?

I want to retrieve the value from the address and the address of the modified variable "i". I want to perform until such an address exists, because it is a row in the table.

```
${f1}       A
${f_temp}   B

While   ${f1} != ${f_temp}
or
While element xpath=//${i} is visible


\  ${F_temp}                Get Text     xpath=//${i}
\  ${i}                     ${i}+1
\  Run Keyword And Continue On Failure   Should be equal  ${f_temp}  ${f1}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm updating my answer because modern Robot Framework does have a [while loop](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#while-loops).

The old answer, do not use this:
Robot Framework does not have a while loop. You must use the FOR-loop and "exit for loop if" keywords to exit. It will run in a finite time, but if you select a large enough number in range, it is close enough for practical purposes.

```
*** Test Cases ***
For Test
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    999999
           Exit For Loop If    ${i} == 9
           Log    ${i}
    END
    Log    Exited
```

Comment: thx for answer. I have second question. Is possible write code like  ${i} 2 and ${link}    xpath=//div/div[${i}]/table...  ??  I can not assign a variable to another variable when it is in the middle of the xpath. RF return me an error like No keyword with name xpath=//div/div[${i}]/table...

Comment: I think you need to use "Set Variable" keyword. Try this: "${link}=    Set Variable    xpath=//div/div[${i}]/table" If this does not work, please make a new question.

Comment: No I am not. Me and the Pekka have even been in same room at same time.

Comment: Note that there is a new syntax for for loops!
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops

Comment: Thank you for comment kuga, I changed code to be in new syntax.

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for the [`Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds) keyword, which enables you to do a similar construction to a while loop. It is much more readable than `FOR` cycles with conditional exiting.

You then use your custom keyword, which fails when you need to end the "loop".

Comment: This generates tons of unwanted errors in the log while waiting for the keyword to succeed especially when the loop is iterated many times even though the final result is passing. Log file will be huge if the variable you are checking for error is long.

Answer (score 1):

This are other kinds of FOR Loops in Robot Framework, I have this on my own notes and its very helpfull.

```
FOR Loop with Upper Bounds Range
    [Documentation]  This gives us a 0 based range
    FOR  ${Index}  IN RANGE  5
      Do Something  ${Index}
      ${RANDOM_STRING} =  Generate Random String  ${Index}
      Log  ${RANDOM_STRING}
    END

FOR Loop with Start and Finish Range
    [Documentation]  No longer a 0 based range because I provided start
    FOR  ${Index}  IN RANGE  1  4
      Do Something  ${Index}
      ${RANDOM_STRING} =  Generate Random String  ${Index}
      Log  ${RANDOM_STRING}
    END

FOR Loop with Start, Finish, and Step Range
    [Documentation]  The counter will jump by 2 each time ("step" value = 2)
    FOR  ${Index}  IN RANGE  1  10  2
       Do Something  ${Index}
       ${RANDOM_STRING} =  Generate Random String  ${Index}
       Log  ${RANDOM_STRING}
    END


#index for elements in for
${index} =    Set Variable    0
    FOR    ${col}    IN    @{cols}
       ${colum}    Format String    css:div[class='v-widget v-has-caption v-caption-on-top'] table[aria-rowcount='{0}'] tbody tr:nth-of-type({1}) td:nth-of-type(10)    ${r_count}    ${col}
        Click element    ${colum}
        press Keys    none    ${net_config.broadcast}
        Press Keys    none    TAB
        Press Keys    none    ${net_config.${index}}
        ${index}=    Evaluate    ${index} + 1
    END
#-------

FOR Loop with List
    @{ITEMS} =  Create List  Item 1  Item 2  Item 3

    FOR  ${MyItem}  IN  @{ITEMS}
       Log  ${MyItem}
    END

Exit a FOR Loop
    @{ITEMS} =  Create List  Item 1  Item 2  Item 3  Item 4

    FOR  ${MyItem}  IN  @{ITEMS}
       Log  ${MyItem}
       Run Keyword If  "${MyItem}" == "Item 3"  Exit For Loop
       Log  Didn't exit yet
    END

    Log  Now we're out of the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer said, Robot doesn't support native WHILE loop.
But this one may help if you insist. 
https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/3235