# How to iterate For loop until certain condition meets?

Tags: for-loop, robotframework

I need to iterate for loop till certain condition meets in Robot Framework.

```
${counter}=  Set Variable  1

    :FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE    ${counter}
    \    Check condition
    \    ${counter} = ${counter} + 1
```

Is it possible to increase the ${counter} variable value here?

[image]

Comment: What you want to use is a while loop, robot framework has not implemented this yet.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328595/how-to-write-a-loop-while-in-robot-framework Apparently there is a workaround: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/3235

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
${counter}=    Set Variable     1
FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE    1     20
    ${counter}=     Evaluate     ${counter} + 1
    Log To Console    ${counter}
    Exit For Loop If     ${counter} == 10
END
```

And FOR loops can be exited using `Exit For Loop` or `Exit For Loop If` keywords. [Keywords documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Exit%20For%20Loop).

EDIT after comments.

Comment: Not working. I've tried this many times. Don't know what's missing here.

Comment: I've added screenshot in question. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Of course it does not work if you need the value to be 10 and you loop it only once. Why not state this 10 condition in the question in the first place?

Comment: Edited answer. Please note that the max number (in this case 20) should be bigger than the condition (10).

Comment: I don't want it to limit till 20 or any other number. Iteration range must increase based on condition. Like in Java: for int i=0 to i<10 {i++}.

Comment: Please make sure your intended use is clear in the question, I'm done with this guessing game.

Comment: Much appreciated. Here, FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE    1     20, I don't want range specified (20). What I want is, ${item} index should be incremented until certain condition meets.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about a while loop. Robot doesn't have a while loop. There's simply no support for it, and robot probably won't support it until at least 2021. The only looping construct is a [for loop](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops).

You seem to have an aversion to setting a limit of 20, but there must be a practical limit to the number of iterations, whether it's 1,000, 10,000, or 1 million or more. Just use a FOR loop that has a huge upper limit, and for all intents and purposes you've created a while loop.

```
FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE    1000000
    Exit FOR loop if  <some condition>
    ${counter}=  evaluate  $counter + 1
END
```

While it doesn't look quite as pretty as `While <some condition>`, the end result will be the same, assuming your condition becomes true at some point before one million iterations.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan. Yes, I know that Robot doesn't have while loop mechanism. That's why I was trying to use for loop iteration till certain condition meets. I thought of implementing logic in python (.py file) also but for my project work, it was not feasible. Nevertheless, Thank you.